# How to extract data from a JSON column from database directly to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

Hi I am new to Pandas in Python and I am trying to extract a JSON data from a particular table in a database. Could someone help me build the dataframe to extract the required data.

Given below are the details.
Table name : Employees
Column name : Profile

Sample column:

{"EmpID":"1","Department":"Support","Role":{"Support":1,"Troubleshoot":2,"Update KBarticles":3},"Team_name":Royals,"Date_Joined":" "}

I need to have the data from the above in separate columns.
EmpID, Role(Support), Role(Troubleshoot), Role(Update KB),Team_Name, Date_Joined

Could someone help me build the dataframe for the above, thanks.

Comment: Please try to format your code- there's an error in your JSON (Royals). Also, can you show an example of your desired output?

Comment: Hi,

Given below is how the data is stored:

{"EmpID":"1","Department":"Support","Role":{1:"Support",2:"Troubleshoot",3:"Update KBarticles"},"Team_name":"Royals","Date_Joined":" "}

Desired output:
As shown in the image

https://imgur.com/a/iFRLJ

Thanks..

Comment: Don't post it as a comment. Edit the question and add it. Also, don't post links to pictures. Show the desired output as text. See more: [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas json normalizer:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

example = '{"EmpID":"1","Department":"Support","Role":{"Support":1,"Troubleshoot":2,"Update KBarticles":3},"Team_name":"Royals","Date_Joined":" "}'

pd.io.json.json_normalize(json.loads(example))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but get the below error when I tried running the query



TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'DataFrame'


Also I am trying to directly query from DB and not pass it manually, in such case could you please help me on how it could be done. Tnx.

Comment: think the error is beacuse you miss a " in your example, copy paste my code and see if it works, about the direct query - I don't know